# In a spreadsheet, I want to copy cells with a negative value onto another cell where there is a floor for negative values

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, google-sheets

In spreadsheet cell B1, the value is -1200.

I want cell B2 to copy the value of B1 and limit (validate?) it to no less than -800.

I'm using google docs but can also use excel if those functions are not available in google docs.

Edit:
 If B1 has the value of 2000, B2 should have the value of 2000.
 If B1 has the value of -2000, B2 should have the value of -800

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't need any maths here. I'm using Excel but I think it is pretty similar in Google.

Suppose that B3 holds floor, no constants in formulae :-)

B2 => =if( b1 > $b$3; b1; $b$3)

b3 position is fixed so you can copy the expression

Comment: identical to the solution I offered except you use a cell reference instead of the constant value...

Comment: Yeeep, sorry. I left the page open so I didn't see your answer some minutes before.

Answer (score 3):

Excel & Google Spreadsheets

```
=Max(B1,-800)
```

Answer (score 1):

Excel formula would be pretty easy, probably similar in Google Spreadsheets:

In B2, put this formula:

`=If(B1<-800,-800,B1)`

This is saying:

If the value in B1 is *less than* -800, then put the value "-800". Otherwise, use the value from B1.  This effectively puts a "floor" or a lower bound on the formula.